# Will it be any difference whether I declare f as global variable or local variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

```
   function functionFunction(str) {
       var f;
      return f=function(obj){
          return str+', '+obj;
      }
  }
  functionFunction('Hello')('world')
```

Here is my code. The function functionFunction will return function f. When I declared variable f in the function functionFunction, the output is" Hello, World". When I declared the variable outside the function functionFunction, the output is the same.(Code as below). But I know in Javascript the global and local variable works on different scope. However, in this case, whether the variable f is global or is local, has no effect on the result. I wonder why

```
 var f;
 function functionFunction(str) {
        return f=function(obj){
            return str+', '+obj;
        }
  }
 functionFunction('Hello')('world')
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** No, there is no functional difference.

When doing `return f= function()` you get a reference to the function and also set the variable `f` even though `f` is never actually used anywhere. Your code would work equally well without the variable as is not being used.

```js
function functionFunction(str) {
  return function(obj) {
    return str + ', ' + obj;
  }
}

let s = functionFunction('Hello')('world');
console.log(s);
```

You could also use ES6 syntax to do this too

```js
const functionFunction = str => {
  return obj => str + ', ' + obj
}

let s = functionFunction('Hello')('world');
console.log(s);
```